# Select a BLOB column from Oracle DB using mybatis

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, mybatis

I'm trying to retrieve the contents of a BLOB column from an Oracle Database using mybatis. There is a table 'Demo' that contains a column 'binfile' of type BLOB. I would like to select the BLOB column and display it as a byte array/raw binary data. I'm using a Oracle thin JDBC driver.

The query in the mybatis mapper looks like this:

```
<mapper namespace="Oracle" >
...
<select id="SelectBinary" resultType="hashmap">
    SELECT binfile from mpdemo.Demo
    </select>
</mapper>
```

If I do this, the result I get looks like this:

```
BINFILE: "oracle.sql.BLOB@5d67eb18"
```

If I do this:

```
<select id="SelectBinaryDup" resultType="hashmap">
  SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(binfile)) from mpdemo.Demo
</select>
```

I obviously get an error saying that the raw variable saying 'PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long' as the image is well over 100 kB, since a VARCHAR2 variable in SQL can support only 2000 bytes.

Is there a solution to this?

I thought of writing a stored proc that reads the BLOB column block by block and writes the output to a file. But that file will be saved on the database server and I can't retrieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the BLOB directly, do `import oracle.sql.BLOB;`

Examples:

```java
BLOB blob = (BLOB)map.get("binfile");

//one way: as array
byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1L, (int)blob.length());
System.out.println(new String(bytes)); //use for text data
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));

//another way: as stream
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data.bin"));
InputStream is = blob.binaryStreamValue();
int b = -1;
while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
    bos.write(b);
}
bos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mapping the field to jdbcType=LONGVARBINARY?

Comment: not working if mapping field to jdbcType=LONGVARBINARY

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to implement a [custom BaseTypeHandler to support Oracle BLOB conversion to byte[] for Mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers).

1. Add the Oracle JDBC driver to your project, you will need `mybatis` dependencies too. If you are using Maven:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
       <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
       <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
       <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
       <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add the [custom BaseTypeHandler for reading byte[] from Oracle BLOB](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) class:

   ```
   @MappedTypes(byte[].class)
   public class OracleBlobTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<byte[]> {
       @Override
       public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i, byte[] bytes, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
           // see setBlobAsBytes method from https://jira.spring.io/secure/attachment/11851/OracleLobHandler.java
           try {
               if (bytes != null) {
                   //prepareLob
                   BLOB blob = BLOB.createTemporary(preparedStatement.getConnection(), true, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);

                   //callback.populateLob
                   OutputStream os = blob.getBinaryOutputStream();
                   try {
                       os.write(bytes);
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       throw new SQLException(e);
                   } finally {
                       try {
                           os.close();
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();//ignore
                       }
                   }
                   preparedStatement.setBlob(i, blob);
               } else {
                   preparedStatement.setBlob(i, (Blob) null);
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new SQLException(e);
           }
       }

       /** see getBlobAsBytes method from https://jira.spring.io/secure/attachment/11851/OracleLobHandler.java */
       private byte[] getBlobAsBytes(BLOB blob) throws SQLException {

           //initializeResourcesBeforeRead
           if(!blob.isTemporary()) {
               blob.open(BLOB.MODE_READONLY);
           }

           //read
           byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1L, (int)blob.length());

           //releaseResourcesAfterRead
           if(blob.isTemporary()) {
               blob.freeTemporary();
           } else if(blob.isOpen()) {
               blob.close();
           }

           return bytes;
       }

       @Override
       public byte[] getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, String columnName) throws SQLException {
           try {
               //use a custom oracle.sql.BLOB
               BLOB blob = (BLOB) resultSet.getBlob(columnName);
               return getBlobAsBytes(blob);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new SQLException(e);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public byte[] getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
           try {
               //use a custom oracle.sql.BLOB
               BLOB blob = (BLOB) resultSet.getBlob(i);
               return getBlobAsBytes(blob);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new SQLException(e);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public byte[] getNullableResult(CallableStatement callableStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
           try {
               //use a custom oracle.sql.BLOB
               BLOB blob = (BLOB) callableStatement.getBlob(i);
               return getBlobAsBytes(blob);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new SQLException(e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the type handlers package to mybatis configuration. As you can see, I am using spring-mybatis:

   ```
   <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
       <property name="typeHandlersPackage" value="package.where.customhandler.is" />
   </bean>
   ```
4. And then, *you can read byte[] from Oracle BLOBs from Mybatis*:

   ```
   public class Bean {
       private byte[] file;
   }

   interface class Dao {
       @Select("select file from some_table where id=#{id}")
       Bean getBean(@Param("id") String id);
   }
   ```

I hope this will help.
This is an adaptation of this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522590/2692914.